# In a Hilbert space, does every nonexpansive mapping have a fixed point?

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-points

In a Hilbert space, does every nonexpansive mapping have a 
fixed point?

For example rotations or mirroring are nonexpansive, but the zero vector is a fixed point, hence the set of fixed points is nonempty. With this logic I can come up with a bunch of examples of nonexpansive mappings, which have nonempty fixed point sets. I cannot come up with an example where both conditions hold, but I believe that the answer on the question is NO.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about translations?

Comment: Yes, translations work!

Comment: In the other direction, you might note that for non-expansive mappings that preserve the unit ball (or any other nonempty closed convex bounded set) the Browder fixed-point theorem applies.

Answer (score 3):

If by non-expansive you mean $\|Tx-Ty\| \leq \|x-y\|$ then  a translation by any non-zero vector ($Tx=x+x_0$) is an obvious example.

Comment: ah right, I was stupid... thank you !